# Django: querying models not related with FK

Tags: django, django-models

I'm developing a Django project. I need to make many queries with the following pattern:

I have two models, not related by a FK, but that can be related by some fields (not their PKs).

I need to query the first model, and annotate it with results from the second model, joined by that field that is not de PK.

I can do it with a Subquery and an OuterRef function.

```
M2_queryset = M2.objects.filter(f1 = OuterRef('f2'))
M1.objects.annotate(b_f3 = Subquery(M2_queryset.values('f3')))
```

But if I need to annotate two columns, I need to do this:

```
M2_queryset = M2.objects.filter(f1 = OuterRef('f2'))
M1.objects.annotate(b_f3 = Subquery(M2_queryset.values('f3'))).annotate(b_f4 = Subquery(M2_queryset.values('f4')))
```

It's very inefficient because of the two identical subqueries.

It would be very interesting doing something like this:

```
M2_queryset = M2.objects.filter(f1 = OuterRef('f2'))
M1.objects.annotate(b_f3, b_f4 = Subquery(M2_queryset.values('f3','f4')))
```

or more interesting something like this and avoiding subqueries:

```
M1.objects.join(M2 on M2.f1 = M1.f2)...
```

For example in this model:

[db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFlbU.png)

I need to do this regular query:

```
select m1.id,m1.f5, sum(m2.f2), sum(m2.f3) 
from M1, M2 
where M1.f1 = M2.f2 
group by 1,2
```

without a fk between f1 and f2.

Comment: An FK does not need to refer to the primary key of another model, it can refer to *any unique* field of the target model.

Comment: I know, but there is no a relationship in the database, there is not a restriction, because it is like a m2m, that could exists or not